# Multiple select values in SelectMenu | DJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to be able to select several values, each of which gives a role.

> Example:
>
> - If I select the value "member", then the SelectMenu gives the role "Member"
> - If I select the value "member" **and** "logs", then the SelectMenu gives the roles "Member" and "logs"

With my current code,

- the SelectMenu gives (or removes) only one role even if I select several.
- The SelectMenu only gives (or removes) the role linked to the first value I select.

***My MessageSelectMenu() :***

```
        const notifications = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId('notifications-select')
            .setPlaceholder(' Mes notifications')
            .setMaxValues(5)
            .setMinValues(0)
            .addOptions([
                {
                    label: 'Changement',
                    emoji: '',
                    description: `Sois notifier des nouveautés & changemements apporter *`,
                    value: 'changement'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Annonce',
                    emoji: '',
                    description: 'Sois notifier des annonces (événements, giveaway...) *',
                    value: 'annonce'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Suggestion',
                    emoji: '',
                    description: "Sois notifier lorsqu'une suggestion est partagée *",
                    value: 'suggestion'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Confession',
                    emoji: '',
                    description: "Sois notifier lorsqu'un membre se confie anonymement",
                    value: 'confession'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Anniversaire',
                    emoji: '',
                    description: "Sois notifier lorsqu'un membre fête son anniversaire",
                    value: 'anniversaire'
                }
            ])
        );
```

**My interactionCreate *(I have only done 2 values so far, I would like to be able to fix the problem before continuing)* :**

```
    MessageEmbed,
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.isSelectMenu()) {
            let choice = interaction.values[0]

            if (choice === 'changement') {
                const changementRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("988719545667702814");
                const nameRole = changementRole.name;

                if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(changementRole.id)) {
                    await interaction.member.roles.add(changementRole);

                    const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#43B17E')
                        .setAuthor({
                            name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                            iconURL: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif'
                        })
                        .setDescription(`Rôle ${changementRole} \`ajouté\` avec succès.`);
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
                        ephemeral: true
                    });
                    return console.log('\x1b[32m', ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est ajouté [${nameRole}]`);

                } else {
                    await interaction.member.roles.remove(changementRole);

                    const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#F04848')
                        .setAuthor({
                            name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                            iconURL: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif'
                        })
                        .setDescription(`Rôle ${changementRole} \`retiré\` avec succès.`);
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
                        ephemeral: true
                    });
                    return console.log('\x1b[32m', ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est retiré [${nameRole}]`);
                }
            } else if (choice === 'annonce') {
                const announceRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("988719685300285520");
                const nameRole = announceRole.name;

                if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(announceRole.id)) {
                    await interaction.member.roles.add(announceRole);

                    const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#43B17E')
                        .setAuthor({
                            name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                            iconURL: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif'
                        })
                        .setDescription(`Rôle ${announceRole} \`ajouté\` avec succès.`);
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
                        ephemeral: true
                    });
                    return console.log('\x1b[32m', ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est ajouté [${nameRole}]`);

                } else {
                    await interaction.member.roles.remove(announceRole);

                    const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#F04848')
                        .setAuthor({
                            name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                            iconURL: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif'
                        })
                        .setDescription(`Rôle ${announceRole} \`retiré\` avec succès.`);
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
                        ephemeral: true
                    });
                    return console.log('\x1b[32m', ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est retiré [${nameRole}]`);
                }
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: `choice` is only the first value of `interaction.values`, so you should do the same for the other selected values.

Comment: Ok, so I have to add
`let choice2 = interaction.values[1]`
`let choice3 = interaction.values[2]`
...
  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the problem is that the value of your `choice` variable is only the first selected menu item.

[`interaction.values`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/SelectMenuInteraction?scrollTo=values) is an array of the selected values of the select menu. As it's an array, you can iterate over these and add these roles:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'interactionCreate',
  async execute(interaction) {
    if (interaction.isSelectMenu()) {
      interaction.values.forEach(async (choice) => {
        if (choice === 'changement') {
          const changementRole =
            interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('988719545667702814');
          const nameRole = changementRole.name;

          if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(changementRole.id)) {
            await interaction.member.roles.add(changementRole);

            const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('#43B17E')
              .setAuthor({
                name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                iconURL:
                  'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif',
              })
              .setDescription(`Rôle ${changementRole} \`ajouté\` avec succès.`);
            await interaction.reply({
              embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
              ephemeral: true,
            });
            return console.log(
              '\x1b[32m',
              ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est ajouté [${nameRole}]`,
            );
          } else {
            await interaction.member.roles.remove(changementRole);

            const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('#F04848')
              .setAuthor({
                name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                iconURL:
                  'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif',
              })
              .setDescription(`Rôle ${changementRole} \`retiré\` avec succès.`);
            await interaction.reply({
              embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
              ephemeral: true,
            });
            return console.log(
              '\x1b[32m',
              ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est retiré [${nameRole}]`,
            );
          }
        } else if (choice === 'annonce') {
          const announceRole =
            interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('988719685300285520');
          const nameRole = announceRole.name;

          if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(announceRole.id)) {
            await interaction.member.roles.add(announceRole);

            const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('#43B17E')
              .setAuthor({
                name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                iconURL:
                  'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif',
              })
              .setDescription(`Rôle ${announceRole} \`ajouté\` avec succès.`);
            await interaction.reply({
              embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
              ephemeral: true,
            });
            return console.log(
              '\x1b[32m',
              ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est ajouté [${nameRole}]`,
            );
          } else {
            await interaction.member.roles.remove(announceRole);

            const confirmationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('#F04848')
              .setAuthor({
                name: 'Mise à jour de ton profil',
                iconURL:
                  'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947816618824724480/948574842087690250/tada_animated.gif',
              })
              .setDescription(`Rôle ${announceRole} \`retiré\` avec succès.`);
            await interaction.reply({
              embeds: [confirmationEmbed],
              ephemeral: true,
            });
            return console.log(
              '\x1b[32m',
              ` [ Roles ] ⇢ [ ${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id}) ] s'est retiré [${nameRole}]`,
            );
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
};
```